# How to flatten frequencies like that

Tags: production, frequency

What I just didn’t work out. No multiband compressor will work that way. It's only a clipper or distortion that can do that.

[image]

Comment: Why are you actually trying to flatten frequencies? Basically the frequency distribution is the very essence of the sound. if you're doing it so the spectrograph "looks pretty" then you're not listening, you're looking. Sound is not assessed by looking.

Comment: This is not a well posed question.  It is merely a statement.  What actual question are you asking?

Comment: Neither compressors nor clipping flatten out the spectrum in that way.

Comment: Sure, it's a terrible question, as asked - but somewhere in there is a reasoning behind **why** this is desired. That question **can** be answered; even if the answer is a frame challenge.

Comment: Just looking at images doesn’t tell us (or you!) whether making any kind of change, including the one that maybe you’re asking about, will make it sound better or worse. What does the thing you’re trying to fix sound like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, use your primary weapon against frequency problems- the EQ!  If any frequencies are consistently too loud, your eq can tame them.

For more erratic problems, there are more specialized solutions.  ReaFIR, available for free with the [ReaPlugs](https://www.reaper.fm/reaplugs/) Plugin bundle, is designed to do exactly this, although you will find that the result is riddled with sonic artefacts and nearly unusable.  There are more expensive options, such as the Soothe plugin and Waves' L3-16, which is a 16 band multiband limiter.  I have no experience with either.

**Beware of using your production tools to solve performance or recording issues.**  If you've synthesized a sound with a nasty resonance, you could probably fix with your synthesis controls.  If you've recorded a sound with a nasty resonance, you could probably fix it by moving somewhere else, or using a different microphone, or working on getting a better instrument tone.

**Some instruments just have resonances, that's part of their sound.**  Flattening them out isn't necessarily fixing anything.

For example, you can clearly see the lead vocal on this professionally recorded, mixed, and mastered rock track.
[image: Spectrum1]

Comment: Excellent answer even in the face of a very unclear question!

Comment: Voxengo Soniformer has 32 bands https://www.voxengo.com/product/soniformer/